# Infinite loop in blocks in ruby

Tags: ruby, infinite-loop

Why does the following piece of code result in an infinite loop of 3's?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]     
a.each {|value| puts a.insert(value,3)}
```

Comment: You know what `insert` does, don't you? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-insert

Comment: What is an infinite loop of 3's?

Comment: It just keeps printing 3 one line after the other

Comment: Then write it like that.

Comment: @user3078066: your code should not be printing only 3's. There should be other characters as well.

Comment: @user3078066 my answer was wrong, [p11y's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25992492/477037) shows what's actually going on.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for pointing that out, I should have read the documentation first :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `insert` changes the original array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
a.each do |value|
  a.insert(value, 3)
  p a
end

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]                   # original, ^ marks current value
#  ^
# [1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]                # inserted 3 at position 1
#     ^
# [1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]             # inserted 3 at position 3
#        ^
# [1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]          # inserted 3 at position 2
#           ^
# [1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]       # inserted 3 at position 2
#              ^
# [1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]    # inserted 3 at position 2
#                 ^
# [1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # inserted 3 at position 2
#                    ^
# ...                                               # continues forever ...
```

What you probably want instead is something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
a.each_index {|index| p a.dup.insert(index, 3) }
# [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 9, 10]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 10]
```

- `each_index` iterates over the indices, not the values. This is likely the correct thing to do here, because `insert` takes an index as first argument.
- `dup` duplicates the array on every iteration so `a` remains unchanged.